# Using regex to replace only non-literals

Tags: regex

I have a list of hundreds of regular expressions. They all have a portion of literals and most also have various matching patterns (like .*, [A-Za-z]+, \d+, etc.). This list gets longer all the time and is automatically generated by someone else (not me), so I cannot edit it manually.

For example, this is a regexp:

```
Clock advanced by .* ticks
```

Which matches:

```
Clock advanced by 319 ticks
```

What I need to do is use the regular expression to replace the non-literal strings with XXX. So for example, for the case above, I need to arrive at:

```
Clock advanced by XXX ticks
```

I can use Java, JavaScript, PHP or bash scripting (and executables) to achieve this.

Comment: So you have a list of regular expressions, and you want to programmatically modify that list to create a list of regular expressions for substituting?

Comment: Why not just escape the strings?

Comment: `non-literal strings` It's not clear what your definition is. Which parts of `(an)?other` or `any|many|more` are considered non-literal?

Answer (score 1):

Use a capture group in the regexp, and a back-reference in the replacement, to copy the parts that you don't want to replace. In Javascript:

```js
str = 'Clock advanced by 219 ticks';
newstr = str.replace(/(Clock advanced by ).*( ticks)/, '$1XXX$2');
alert(newstr);
```